# PHP form validation submitting

Tags: php, forms, validation, submit

This code works for validation, but I cannot get it to work with submitting and I can't figure out why. As far as I can tell the issue is in the if statement at the end of the PHP, starting with if((strlen($valid_first_name)
I have looked through many instructional sites but can't figure out the issue. I would appreciate and help or guidance on this! Thank you!

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];  
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];
$make1 = $_POST['make1']; 
$model1 = $_POST['model1'];  
$vehicle_type_id1 = $_POST['vehicle_type_id1']; 
$pickup_city = $_POST['pickup_city']; 
$pickup_state_code = $_POST['pickup_state_code'];
$dropoff_city = $_POST['dropoff_city']; 
$dropoff_state_code = $_POST['dropoff_state_code'];  
$vehicle_runs = $_POST['vehicle_runs'];
$ship_via_id = $_POST['ship_via_id'];
$estimated_ship_date = $_POST['estimated_ship_date'];


// First Name
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z -]{3,20}$/",$first_name))
 {
       $valid_first_name=$first_name;
 }
else
{  
    $error_first_name='Enter valid First Name.';  
}
// Last Name
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z -]{3,20}$/",$last_name))
 {
       $valid_last_name=$last_name;
 }
else
{  
    $error_last_name='Enter valid Last Name.';  
}
// Phone
if (preg_match("/^[0-9 -]{7,20}$/",$phone))
 {
       $valid_phone=$phone;
 }
else
{  
    $error_phone='Enter valid Phone Number.';  
}
// Email 
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/", $email))
 {
       $valid_email=$email; 
 }
else
{  
    $error_email='Enter valid Email.';  
}
// Year
if (preg_match("/^[0-9 -]{2,20}$/",$year1))
 {
       $valid_year1=$year1;
 }
else
{  $error_year1='Enter valid Vehicle Year.';  }

// Make

if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{2,25}$/",$make1))
 {
      $valid_make1=$make1;
 }
else
{  
    $error_make1='Enter valid Vehicle Make.';  
}
// Model

if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{2,25}$/",$model1))
 {
      $valid_model1=$model1;
 }
else
{  
    $error_model1='Enter valid Vehicle Model.';  
}

// Vehicle Type
if ($vehicle_type_id1==00)
 {
        $error_vehicle_type_id1='Select Vehicle Type'; 
 }
else
{  
$valid_vehicle_type_id1=$vehicle_type_id1;

}
// Pickup City
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{3,20}$/",$pickup_city))
 {
       $valid_pickup_city=$pickup_city;
 }
else
{  
    $error_pickup_city='Enter valid Pickup City.';  
}
// Pickup state
if ($pickup_state_code==00)
 {
        $error_pickup_state_code='Select Pickup State.'; 
 }
else
{  
$valid_pickup_state_code=$pickup_state_code;

}
// Dropoff City
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{3,20}$/",$dropoff_city))
 {
       $valid_dropoff_city=$dropoff_city;
 }
else
{  
    $error_dropoff_city='Enter valid Dropoff City.';  
}
// Dropoff state
if ($dropoff_state_code==00)
 {
        $error_dropoff_state_code='Select Dropoff State.'; 
 }
else
{  
$valid_dropoff_state_code=$dropoff_state_code;

}
// Vehicle Runs
if ($vehicle_runs==00)
 {
        $error_vehicle_runs='Does your vehicle run?'; 
 }
else
{  
$valid_vehicle_runs=$vehicle_runs;

}
// Ship Via
if ($ship_via_id==00)
 {
        $error_ship_via_id='Select how to ship.'; 
 }
else
{  
$valid_ship_via_id=$ship_via_id;

}
// Estimated Shipping Date
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/",$estimated_ship_date))
 {
       $valid_estimated_ship_date=$estimated_ship_date;
 }
else
{  
    $error_estimated_ship_date='Enter valid Shipping Date.';  
}

if((strlen($valid_first_name)>0)&&(strlen($valid_last_name)>0)&&(strlen($valid_phone)>0)&&(strlen($valid_email)>0)&&(strlen($valid_year1)>0)&&(strlen($valid_make1)>0)&&(strlen($valid_model1)>0)&&(strlen($valid_vehicle_type_id1)>0)&&(strlen($valid_pickup_city)>0)&&($valid_pickup_state_code>0)&&(strlen($valid_dropoff_city)>0)&&($valid_dropoff_state_code>0)&&($valid_vehicle_runs>0)&& ($valid_ship_via_id>0)&& strlen($valid_estimated_ship_date>0))
{
//mysql_query(' SQL insert statement');
header("Location: thanks.html");

}


}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Reg Form</title>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/structure.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/9lessons.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.err
{
font-size:11px;
padding-left:10px;
color:#CC0000;
float:left;

}
input
{
float:left;

}
</style>

</head>

<body id="public">
    <div style="height:30px"></div>

<div id="container">

<div style="height:30px"></div>

<form autocomplete="on"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=""  name="form">



<ul>


<li id="foli1"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">
        First Name          </label>
    <div>
        <input id="first_name"          name="first_name"           type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_first_name; ?>"            maxlength="255"             tabindex="1"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_first_name; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="foli2"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field2">
        Last Name           </label>
    <div>
        <input id="last_name"           name="last_name"            type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_last_name; ?>"             maxlength="255"             tabindex="2"                        />
        </div>
        <div><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_last_name; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="foli3"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">
        Phone</label>
    <div>
        <input id="phone"           name="phone"            type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_phone; ?>"             maxlength="255"             tabindex="3"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_phone; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="foli4"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field3">
        Email           </label>
    <div>
        <input id="email"           name="email"            type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_email; ?>"             maxlength="255"             tabindex="4"  /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="foli5"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title5" for="Field5">
        Year            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="year1"           name="year1"            type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_year1; ?>"             maxlength="255"             tabindex="5"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_year1; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli6"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title6" for="Field6">
        Make            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="make1"           name="make1"            type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_make1; ?>"             maxlength="255"             tabindex="6"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_make1; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli7"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title7" for="Field7">
        Model           </label>
    <div>
        <input id="model1"          name="model1"           type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_model1; ?>"            maxlength="255"             tabindex="7"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_model1; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="foli8"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title8" for="Field8">
        Vehicle type        </label>
    <div>
        <select id="vehicle_type_id1"           name="vehicle_type_id1"             class="field select medium"             tabindex="8" style="float:left"> 
                        <option value="00">Gender</option><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option>
          </select><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_vehicle_type_id1; ?></span>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli9"      class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title9" for="Field9">
        pickup city</label>
    <div>
        <input id="pickup_city"             name="pickup_city"          type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_pickup_city; ?>"           maxlength="255"             tabindex="9"                        /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_pickup_city; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli10"         class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title10" for="Field10">
        pickup  state       </label>
    <div>
        <select id="pickup_state_code"          name="pickup_state_code"            class="field select medium"             tabindex="10" style="float:left"> 
                        <option value="00">Gender</option><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option>
          </select><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_pickup_state_code; ?></span>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli11"         class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title11" for="Field11">
        Dropoff City        </label>
    <div>
        <input id="dropoff_city"            name="dropoff_city"             type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_dropoff_city; ?>"          maxlength="255"             tabindex="11"                       /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_dropoff_city; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli12"         class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title12" for="Field12">
        Dropoff State       </label>
    <div>
        <select id="pickup_state_code"          name="pickup_state_code"            class="field select medium"             tabindex="12" style="float:left"> 
                        <option value="00">Gender</option><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option>
          </select><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_pickup_state_code; ?></span>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli13"         class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title13" for="Field13">
        Runs?           </label>
    <div>
        <select id="vehicle_runs"           name="vehicle_runs"             class="field select medium"             tabindex="13" style="float:left"> 
                        <option value="00">Gender</option><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option>
          </select><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_vehicle_runs; ?></span>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foli14"         class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title14" for="Field14">
        Ship    Via?        </label>
    <div>
        <select id="ship_via_id"            name="ship_via_id"          class="field select medium"             tabindex="14" style="float:left"> 
                        <option value="00">Gender</option><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option>
          </select><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_ship_via_id; ?></span>
    </div>
    </li>

     <li id="foli15"        class="   ">
    <label class="desc" id="title15" for="Field15">
        Ship    Date        </label>
    <div>
        <input id="estimated_ship_date"             name="estimated_ship_date"          type="text"             class="field text medium"           value="<?php echo $valid_estimated_ship_date; ?>"           maxlength="255"             tabindex="15"                       /><span class="err"> <?php echo $error_estimated_ship_date; ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="foli15"         class="   "></li>


<li class="buttons">
                <input  type="submit" value="Submit" style=" background:#0060a1; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; border:1px solid #0060a1"/>
      </li>


</ul>
</form>
<div style="height:20px"></div>
</div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does _"I cannot get it to work with submitting"_ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are not closing right your (neverending) last if, you have it ending like this:

```
... && strlen($valid_estimated_ship_date>0))
```

and it should be:

```
.. && (strlen($valid_estimated_ship_date)>0))
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of problems with the last line of code you mentioned, try this:

```
if(strlen($valid_first_name) > 0 && strlen($valid_last_name) > 0 && strlen($valid_phone) > 0 && strlen($valid_email) > 0 && strlen($valid_year1) > 0 && strlen($valid_make1) > 0 && strlen($valid_model1) > 0 && strlen($valid_vehicle_type_id1) > 0 && strlen($valid_pickup_city) > 0 && strlen($valid_pickup_state_code) > 0 && strlen($valid_dropoff_city) > 0 && strlen($valid_dropoff_state_code) > 0 && strlen($valid_vehicle_runs) > 0 && strlen($valid_ship_via_id) > 0 && strlen($valid_estimated_ship_date) > 0) {
    //mysql_query(' SQL insert statement');
    header("Location: thanks.html");
}
```

You were missing some strlen functions. You might want to consider consolidating that code though, it's a little cumbersome.

Comment: apparently this isn't posting the fields... I was hoping they would follow

Answer (score 1):

when we did something like this we initiated a variable at the top called

```
$valid = true;
```

in every else part make

```
$valid = false;
```

at the end you can ask

```
if($valid)
    header("Location: thanks.html");
```