# How to validate form with php and show the error text in html

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to validate form using php and then make the input save in json file. I used span class to echo the error message from writer.php to html. But it's not echo the error text in html, it's refer to writer.php with blank page.

```
<head>
    <title>Data Buku</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ribeye+Marrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class="center">
    <h1>Data Buku</h1>

        <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

        <hr>

        <form action="writer.php" method="post">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error;?></span>
            <h2>Informasi Pengarang</h2>
            Nama: <br><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" />
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $namaErr;?></span><br>
            Nomor Telepon: <br><input type="text" name="telepon" id="telepon" />
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nomorErr;?></span><br>
            e-Mail: <br><input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>

            <h2>Tulisan</h2>
            Judul: <br><input type="text" name="judul" id="judul" />
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $judulErr;?></span><br>
            Konten: <br><textarea name = "konten" rows="6" cols="50" id="konten"></textarea>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $kontenErr;?></span><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name = submit value="Create" />
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>
</div>      
</body>
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
    // Append new form data in json string saved in json file

    // path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'dataInJson.json';

    // error message
$namaErr = "";
$nomorErr = "";
$emailErr = "";
$judulErr = "";
$kontenErr = "";

    // check if all form data are submited, else output error message
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
    if(empty($_POST['nama'])) {
        $namaErr = "Write your name";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['telepon'])){
        $nomorErr = "Write the phone number";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
        $emailErr = "Write the email";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['judul'])){
        $judulErr = "Write the title";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['konten'])) {
        $kontenErr = "Write the content";
    }
    else {

    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $data = array(
      'nama'=> $_POST['nama'],
      'telepon'=> $_POST['telepon'],
      'email'=> $_POST['email'],
      'judul'=> $_POST['judul'],
      'konten'=> $_POST['konten'],
    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'dataInJson.json';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $data;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "dataInJson.json"
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('dataInJson.json', $jsondata)){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted");</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Tidak dapat menyimpan data di "dataInJson.json"';
    }
  }
}
    else echo 'Form fields not submited';
?>
```

Comment: Are these on the same page?

Comment: No, there are two pages, html and php

Comment: Ok I combined it to one so the errors work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need the page to submit to itself unless you did an AJAX solution so this would all have to be on one page:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    class   ValidateInfo
        {
            public  $errors;
            public  $message;
            public  $data;
            public  function Check($payload = array(),$type = "error",$mess = "unknown",$validate = array())
                {
                    $trimmed                =   trim($payload[$type]);

                    if(!empty($validate)) {
                            // Strip out everything but numbers and letters and a couple of symbols.
                            if(in_array('digits',$validate) && in_array('letters',$validate)) {
                                    $this->data[$type]  =   preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s\-\_]/','',$trimmed);
                                }
                            // Strip out all but numbers
                            elseif(in_array('digits',$validate)) {
                                    $this->data[$type]  =   preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$trimmed);
                                }
                            // Strip out letters
                            elseif(in_array('letters',$validate)) {
                                    $this->data[$type]  =   preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s\-\_]/','',$trimmed);
                                }
                            // Re-assign data type to consolidate
                            $this->data[$type]          =   (!isset($this->data[$type]))? $trimmed:$this->data[$type];

                            // Check if data is an email
                            if(in_array('email',$validate)) {
                                    $this->data[$type]  =   (filter_var($this->data[$type], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))? $this->data[$type]:'';
                                }

                            // Strip out html tags
                            if(in_array('strip',$validate)) {
                                    $this->data[$type]  =   strip_tags($this->data[$type]);
                                }
                        }

                    if(!isset($this->data[$type]))
                        $this->data[$type]  =   $trimmed;

                    $this->errors[$type]    =   (empty($this->data[$type]))? 1:0;
                    $this->message[$type]   =   $mess;
                }
        }

    // Creat instance of info processor
    $info   =   new ValidateInfo(); 

    // check if all form data are submited, else output error message
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            // Checks empty fields
            $info->Check($_POST,'nama','Write your name',array('letters','digits'));
            $info->Check($_POST,'telepon','Write the phone number',array('digits'));
            $info->Check($_POST,'email','Write the email',array('email'));
            $info->Check($_POST,'judul','Write the title',array('letters','digits'));
            $info->Check($_POST,'konten','Write the content', array('letters','digits','strip'));

            if(array_sum($info->errors) == 0) {

                    // path and name of the file
                    $filetxt    =   'dataInJson.json';

                    // Assign stored data
                    $data       =   $info->data;

                    // path and name of the file
                    $filetxt    =   'dataInJson.json';

                    // to store all form data
                    $arr_data   =   array();        

                    // check if the file exists
                    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
                            // gets json-data from file
                            $jsondata   =   file_get_contents($filetxt);

                            // converts json string into array
                            $arr_data   =   json_decode($jsondata, true);

                            // appends the array with new form data
                            $arr_data[] =   $data;

                            // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
                            $jsondata   =   json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

                            // saves the json string in "dataInJson.json"
                            // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
                            if(file_put_contents('dataInJson.json', $jsondata)) {
                                    $info->errors['success']    =   true; ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    alert("Data has been submitted");
                                </script>
                            <?php }
                            else {
                                    $info->message['general']['put_file']   =   'Tidak dapat menyimpan data di "dataInJson.json"';
                                }
                        }
                    else {
                            $info->message['general']['bad_file']   =   'No file exists';
                        }
                }
        }
    else 
        $info->message['general']['submit'] =   'Form fields not submited'; ?>
<head>
<title>Data Buku</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ribeye+Marrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<style>
.error { color: red; clear: left; float: left; display: inline-block; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; }
input,
textarea    { float: left; clear: left; display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; color: #333; padding: 10px; }
label   { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #888; float: left; clear: left; display: inline-block; }
div.roadie  { width: 500px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; display: inline-block; float: left; clear: both; padding: 10px; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="center">
<h1>Data Buku</h1>

    <?php if(isset($info->errors['success'])) { ?>
        <h2>Thank you!</h2>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <hr>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php if(isset($info->message['general'])) {
            foreach($info->message['general'] as $_error) { ?>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $_error; ?></span><br>
            <?php
                }
        } ?>

        <h2>Informasi Pengarang</h2>
        <div class="roadie">
            <label for="nama">Nama:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama"<?php if(isset($info->data['nama'])) { ?> value="<?php echo strip_tags($info->data['nama']); ?>" /><?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($info->errors['nama']) && $info->errors['nama'] == 1) { ?><span class="error">* <?php echo $info->message['nama']; ?></span><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="roadie">
            <label for="telepon">Nomor Telepon:</label>
            <input type="text" name="telepon" id="telepon"<?php if(isset($info->data['telepon'])) { ?> value="<?php echo strip_tags($info->data['telepon']); ?>"<?php } ?> />
        <?php if(isset($info->errors['telepon']) && $info->errors['telepon'] == 1) { ?><span class="error">* <?php echo $info->message['telepon']; ?></span><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="roadie">
            <label for="email">e-Mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"<?php if(isset($info->data['email'])) { ?> value="<?php echo strip_tags($info->data['email']); ?>"<?php } ?> />
        <?php if(isset($info->errors['email']) && $info->errors['email'] == 1) { ?><span class="error">* <?php echo $info->message['email']; ?></span><br><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="roadie">
        <h2>Tulisan</h2>
            <label for="judul">Judul:</label>
            <input type="text" name="judul" id="judul"<?php if(isset($info->data['judul'])) { ?> value="<?php echo strip_tags($info->data['judul']); ?>"<?php } ?> />
        <?php if(isset($info->errors['judul']) && $info->errors['judul'] == 1) { ?><span class="error">* <?php echo $info->message['judul']; ?></span><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="roadie">
            <label for="konten">Konten:</label>
            <textarea name = "konten" rows="6" cols="50" id="konten"><?php if(isset($info->data['konten'])) {  echo strip_tags($info->data['konten']); } ?></textarea>
        <?php if(isset($info->errors['konten']) && $info->errors['konten'] == 1) { ?><span class="error">* <?php echo $info->message['konten']; ?></span><br><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name = submit value="Create" />
        <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: My json file has working when i ask this question. I just can't validate my form

Comment: What part is not working on the validation? Here is a working demo of the above validation: http://www.xolifestyleworldwide.com/client_assets/workboard.php

Comment: I have added the ability for the form to re-insert any answers that have been filled out so not only will it validate data on submit, whatever part of the data the user has already filled out will fill in the fields again so people don't have to rewrite the form from the beginning. See the demo

Comment: Providing a class is much more complicated than OP's code. How do you assume he can understand it?

Comment: It's 13-line class of which all functionality *user3396* does in their procedural code. The class accomplishes the same thing in 1/3 less lines and is arguably that much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How to make more complete validation with preg_match like [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654247/php-form-validation-submitting?

Comment: The validate is modified with some `preg_replace()` and other validation you can modify at will.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else statements are wrong. Your else execute only if !empty($_POST['konten']). 
I suggest you, pull errors in to one array, stored in session in redirect user (if scripts in different files) and show content of errors array. If you have trouble with logic, view this question here - [PHP form validation submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654247/php-form-validation-submitting)